# Автоматическое монтирование раздела жесткого диска

Tags: c#, dos, c, java, c++

Здравствуйте. Стоит Ubuntu 13.04+Windows 8. Есть раздел жесткого диска W: и он играет роль хранилища для Apache.
В Ubuntu он монтируется в /var/www, а в Windows просто W: и все настроено на него. Я себе так сделал, чтоб можно было под разными осями кодить без переносов файлов, да и просто очень удобно - типа рабочий диск.
Проблема в том, что Ubuntu при монтировании удаляет букву и под виндой приходится постоянно вручную назначать. Причем Ubuntu затирает букву, даже когда я в нее не захожу - наверно еще на этапе grub.
Кто-нибудь знает как кодом (С/С++/С#, Java, DOS .bat и т.д.) написать скрипт/программу под винду, чтоб можно было добавить в автозапуск и он при входе автоматически монтировался.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, я просто подумал, что тут все же вопрос больше в программировании. Хотя пожалуй, может на руткоде помогут это дело решить без программирования.

Comment: Да, согласен, здесь ему тоже самое место. Можете для порядка там просто продублировать, вдруг кто ответит, а вообще чутьё подсказывает, что вам самому придётся решить эту задачу)) Я сам с Mac OS/Gentoo работаю, поэтому не подскажу ничего, просто люблю такие задачки. Удачи вам!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, продублировал и там. Спасибо. Просто нагуглить ничего толкового не получается - везде просто инструкции как подключить диск...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуй, не предоставлю полного решения, но возможно подтолку вас в правильном направлении. Прочитав вашу задачу думаю вам нужно испортировать функции из kernel32.dll. Насколько я понял, вам может подойти SetVolumeMountPoint метод.

[SetVolumeMountPoint - w32api - Справочник по Windows API](http://w32api.narod.ru/functions/SetVolumeMountPoint.html)

Попробуйте. Посмотрите так же [C# how to mount and unmount a virtual drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJF2j2gYcCY). Не совмем то, но что бы понять принцип.

Comment: @Макс Коняев, Спасибо. Это уже должно помочь